# Linq with anonymous methods

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm just getting started with LINQ, and I'm having some troubles.

Say I wanted to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<String[]> = from s in listOfStrings
                      where () => {
                          int sum = 0;
                          for (int i=0; i<s.Length(); i++)
                          {
                              sum += s[i];
                          }
                          return sum < 50;
                      }
                      select () =>
                      {
                          String[] t = new String[s.Length()];
                          for (int i=0; i<s.Length(); i++)
                          {
                              t[i] = s[i].toString();
                          }
                          return t;
                      }
```

Basically I want to get an array of characters as string values in from strings in `listOfStrings` that have a sum smaller than 50.

This is just an example though, It would be hard to think of a more useless function huh, I'm just trying to find out how to execute stuff in lambda functions within linq, without making a new function to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to mixing up query syntax with method call syntax.

Comment: Is your `listOfStrings` type `List<string[]>` or `List<int[]>` ?

Comment: @tsukimi The function does not calculate the length, it calculates the sum of all characters

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal List<string[]>

Comment: Do you want the integer value when you take `s[i]` or do you want the character value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the method-chaining syntax instead of the query syntax (i.e. `listOfStrings.Where(...)`), you can stick the lambda in there.

Comment: OK, I'll look that up, but what's the basic difference?

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda functions is probably easier in this case...

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" };
IEnumerable<string[]> result = 

    // restrict to strings where the sum of ASCII values is < 1000
    listOfStrings.Where(item => item.Sum(ch => (int)ch) < 1000)

    // select each as an array of strings
    .Select(item => item.Select(ch => ch.ToString()).ToArray());

// result:  { { "f", "o", "o" }, { "b", "a", "r" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might help you, I haven't compiled it so it might be some bug in the code but the concepts are there:

```
var result = listOfStrings.Where(y => y.Split().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => int.Parse(y)) < 50).Select(y => y.Split());
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps:

```
listOfString.Where(s => s.Length < 50).ToArray();
```